# How get i make this procedure faster?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this store procedure and i need to get all dates for that  nosologico for this user. But for the moment I only get the dates but the it take 5 seconds.

can i do it faster i try to do the join not with ',' but with 'join' but i have some errors . can anyone help

This is my SQL:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE G_TICKETS_BY_STATO_CHIUSO(USERIDRICHIEDENTEP IN VARCHAR2, result_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

IS
    rc SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

    OPEN rc FOR SELECT DISTINCT  T.ID, a.NOME, a.COGNOME, T.OPERAZIONE 
    FROM TICKET_NOTIFICE T, RICOVERO r, ANAGRAFICA a ,PS_METADATA M,AMB_IMPEGNATIVE C, AMB_METADATA D
    WHERE (T.USERIDRICHIEDENTE=USERIDRICHIEDENTEP and  T.stato = '1' and T.NOTIFICATION='0' AND REGEXP_SUBSTR (T.NOSOLOGICO, '[^AMB_]+$',1,1)=C.ID_AMB_METADATI AND
    C.ID_AMB_METADATI=D.ID_AMB_METADATI AND D.IDASSISTITO=a.IDASSISTITO)
   OR (T.USERIDRICHIEDENTE=USERIDRICHIEDENTEP and  T.stato = '1' and T.NOTIFICATION='0' AND T.NOSOLOGICO=r.NOSOLOGICO AND r.IDANAGRAFICA=a.ID ) 
   or (T.USERIDRICHIEDENTE=USERIDRICHIEDENTEP and  T.stato = '1' and T.NOTIFICATION='0' AND REGEXP_SUBSTR (T.NOSOLOGICO, '[^PS_]+$',1,1)=M.EPISODIOPSNUM AND M.IDANAGRAFICA=a.ID);

    result_cursor := rc;

END;
```

The table looks like this and the datas for the user are as below:
[image]

Comment: Switching to modern, explicit `JOIN` operator will not make any difference in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are creating a cartesian product in your query. Basically there are three different queries that you can union.

```
select distinct t.id
               ,a.nome
               ,a.cognome
               ,t.operazione
  from ticket_notifice t
      ,anagrafica      a
      ,amb_impegnative c
      ,amb_metadata    d
 where t.useridrichiedente = useridrichiedentep
   and t.stato = '1'
   and t.notification = '0'
   and regexp_substr(t.nosologico, '[^AMB_]+$', 1, 1) = c.id_amb_metadati
   and c.id_amb_metadati = d.id_amb_metadati
   and d.idassistito = a.idassistito
union
select distinct t.id
               ,a.nome
               ,a.cognome
               ,t.operazione
  from ticket_notifice t
      ,ricovero        r
      ,anagrafica      a
 where t.useridrichiedente = useridrichiedentep
   and t.stato = '1'
   and t.notification = '0'
   and t.nosologico = r.nosologico
   and r.idanagrafica = a.id
union
select distinct t.id
               ,a.nome
               ,a.cognome
               ,t.operazione
  from ticket_notifice t
      ,anagrafica      a
      ,ps_metadata     m
 where t.useridrichiedente = useridrichiedentep
   and t.stato = '1'
   and t.notification = '0'
   and regexp_substr(t.nosologico, '[^PS_]+$', 1, 1) = m.episodiopsnum
   and m.idanagrafica = a.id
```